# Counting occurrences of Value in Multiple Selection with GoogleSheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, multipleselection

I have a column, that contains multiple selection value like this

[image]

How to count occurrences of values in multiple selection with pivot table or gg sheets function?

I dont have any ideas for this problem. Can calculated by appscript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) function. Assuming your data is in `A2:A6`, the formula would be:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   QUERY(
     TOCOL(SPLIT(A2:A6,", "),3),
     "select Col1, count(Col1)
      group by Col1
      label count(Col1) ''"))
```

[image]

This formula also accepts open ranges, like `A2:A`.

Comment: Thank you. It's work. But if i got a pivot table countA column A and group by Column A. How can I sum and group by column A?

Comment: please create a new question and add example of your data and desired result.

Answer (score 1):

You will need two formulas for this:

1. Extract unique values:

   ```cpp
   =sort(unique(flatten(map(B3:B5, lambda(v, if(isblank(v),, split(v, ", ")))))))
   ```

   Here `B3:B5` is the range of the data with multiple selection. It sorts the values alphabetically and assumes that the separator is a comma followed by a space: `,` .
2. Count number of occurrences of the list of separate values in the data:

   ```cpp
   =map(D3:D7, lambda(v, if(isblank(v),, counta(filter(B3:B5, regexmatch("^"&B3:B5&"$", v))))))
   ```

   Here `D3:D7` is the rage of the values we generated in step 1, and `B3:B5` is the original data with multiple selection. The formula assumes that within one selection each value appears only once.

This is how it looks in a spreadsheet:

[image: Example of the formulas]

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want to find the count of values selected from the dropdown for a given cell.

You can do it using Google sheets function itself.

Let's say you want to find number of comma separated values in the cell A2. Use the below formula to do that.

=COUNTA(SPLIT(A2,","))